# Tips on How to Move Location-connecting Code from Fragment to MainActivity?

Tags: java, android, listview, android-fragments

So I have an app that started its life having 4 separate activities, but recently I decided it would be better to have 1 main activity and 4 fragments instead.

My issue now is that 2 of my activities from before, which are now fragments, have location-connecting code contained within them and I need to move the code into my MainActivity for the app to properly request location access, etc, without crashing.

The code in each of the 2 fragments are pretty much the same, so I'll only show one of the 2 fragments in my examples below.

One of my main concerns arises with this particular code:

```
private void handleNewLocation(Location location) {

        Log.i("TEST handleNewLocation", "Called handleNewLocation");
        // Returns the current adapter in use by the ListView supplied (mListView).
        LocationsAdapter adapter = (LocationsAdapter) mListView.getAdapter();
        adapter.setCurrentLocation(location);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

As you may be able to see, the code has references to the ListView that the fragment makes use of to get the in-use adapter for that ListView: `LocationsAdapter adapter = (LocationsAdapter) mListView.getAdapter();`

I don't know how I would move this code into the MainActivity and still somehow reference the ListView from the fragment. To add to that issue, I also need to use the same type of code again in the MainActivity, but reference the *other* ListView in the second fragment of the 2 as well.

Here is one of my Fragments and also the MainActivity below it.

**Locations Fragment:**

```
public class Locations extends Fragment implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener {

    public Locations() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    private static final int PERMISSION_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION = 100;

    private final static int CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 9000;

    private static final String LOG_TAG = Locations.class.getName();

    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

    private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;

    Location mLocation = new Location(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

    private ListView mListView;

    public List<Word> locations = new ArrayList<>();

    // If the app already has the permission to access the user's location at high accuracy
    // (fine location), then connect to the GoogleApiClient.
    // If not, no connection-handling methods will be called.
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                           String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case PERMISSION_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION: {

                // Permission was granted, yay! Do the location-related task you need to do.
                if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(),
                        ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.word_list, container, false);

        mListView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.list);

        // The following code checks if the app has permission to access the user's fine location,
        // and requests the permission if necessary:
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            // Should we show an explanation?
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(getActivity(),
                    ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {

                // Show an explanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
                // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
                // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.
                new MaterialStyledDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                        .setTitle(R.string.title_location_permission)
                        .setDescription(R.string.text_location_permission)
                        .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_place_white_48dp)
                        .withDialogAnimation(true)
                        .setPositiveText(android.R.string.ok)
                        .onPositive(new MaterialDialog.SingleButtonCallback() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(@NonNull MaterialDialog dialog, @NonNull DialogAction which) {
                                //Prompt the user once explanation has been shown
                                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(),
                                        new String[]{ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                                        PERMISSION_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
                            }
                        })
                        .setNegativeText(android.R.string.no)
                        .show();

            } else {

                // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), new String[]{ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                        PERMISSION_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);

                // PERMISSION_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION is an
                // app-defined int constant. The callback method gets the
                // result of the request.
            }
        }

        // Create the GoogleAPIClient object.
        if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
            mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getActivity())
                    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                    .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                    .build();
        }

        // Create the LocationRequest object
        mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create()
                .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)
                .setInterval(10 * 1000)        // 10 seconds, in milliseconds
                .setFastestInterval(1 * 1000); // 1 second, in milliseconds\


        locations.add(new Word("Bristol", R.drawable.bristol,
                41.674009, -71.279006));
        locations.add(new Word("Warren", R.drawable.warren_harbor,
                41.730647, -71.282688));
        locations.add(new Word("Newport", R.drawable.newport_breakers,
                41.486677, -71.315144));
        locations.add(new Word("Jamestown", R.drawable.jamestown,
                41.496313, -71.368435));
        locations.add(new Word("Beavertail Lighthouse", R.drawable.beavertail,
                41.458054, -71.395744));
        locations.add(new Word("Providence", R.drawable.providence,
                41.830279, -71.414955));
        locations.add(new Word("Roger Williams Park", R.drawable.roger_williams_park,
                41.785836, -71.418525));
        locations.add(new Word("Colt State Park", R.drawable.colt_state_park,
                41.682970, -71.297362));
        locations.add(new Word("Blithewold", R.drawable.blithewold,
                41.6540652,-71.2681633));
        locations.add(new Word("Narragansett", R.drawable.narragansett,
                41.433179,-71.457148));
        locations.add(new Word("Barrington", R.drawable.barrington_town_hall,
                41.740674, -71.308610));

        ViewCompat.setNestedScrollingEnabled(mListView, true);

        mListView.setAdapter(new LocationsAdapter(getActivity(), locations, mLocation));

        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        // If the app already has the permission to access the user's location at high accuracy
        // (fine location), then connect to the GoogleApiClient.
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(),
                ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED || mGoogleApiClient != null) {
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }
        super.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        // If the app already has the permission to access the user's location at high accuracy
        // (fine location), then connect to the GoogleApiClient.
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(),
                ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }
        super.onResume();

        // Instantiate the locations ArrayList.
        locations = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        // If the user has paused the app and the GoogleApiClient is currently connected,
        // remove location updating, and disconnect from the GoogleApiClient.
        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient,
                    this);
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();

            locations.clear();
        }
    }

    public void onStop() {
        // If the user has stopped the app, disconnect from the GoogleApiClient.
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        super.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Location services connected.");

        mLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);

        if (mLocation == null) {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient,
                    mLocationRequest, this);
        } else {
            handleNewLocation(mLocation);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Location services suspended. Please reconnect.");
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        if (connectionResult.hasResolution()) {
            try {
                // Start an Activity that tries to resolve the error
                connectionResult.startResolutionForResult(getActivity(),
                        CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST);
            } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Location services connection failed with code " +
                    connectionResult.getErrorCode());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        handleNewLocation(location);
    }

    private void handleNewLocation(Location location) {

        Log.i("TEST handleNewLocation", "Called handleNewLocation");
        // Returns the current adapter in use by the ListView supplied (mListView).
        LocationsAdapter adapter = (LocationsAdapter) mListView.getAdapter();
        adapter.setCurrentLocation(location);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

**MainActivity:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);

        CategoryAdapter adapter = new CategoryAdapter(this, getSupportFragmentManager());

        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

        // Keeps all 4 Fragments active at once
        viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);

        final SmartTabLayout tabLayout = (SmartTabLayout ) findViewById(R.id.viewpagertab);

        final LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(tabLayout.getContext());
        final Resources res = tabLayout.getContext().getResources();

        tabLayout.setCustomTabView(new SmartTabLayout.TabProvider() {

            @Override
            public View createTabView(ViewGroup container, int position, PagerAdapter adapter) {

                AppCompatImageView icon = (AppCompatImageView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_bar_icon,container,
                        false);

                switch (position) {
                    case 0:
                        icon.setImageDrawable(res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_place_white_24dp));
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        icon.setImageDrawable(res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_restaurant_white_24dp));
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        icon.setImageDrawable(res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_wallpaper_white_24dp));
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        icon.setImageDrawable(res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_account_balance_white_24dp));
                        break;
                    default:
                        throw new IllegalStateException("Invalid position: " + position);
                }
                return icon;
            }
        });

        tabLayout.setViewPager(viewPager);

        // Fragment/Tab Titles
        final String[] mTitleNames = {"Locations", "Food", "Photos", "History"};

        // Default actionbar title
        setActionBarTitle(mTitleNames[0]);

        // Set actionbar title when tab is selected
        tabLayout.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                setActionBarTitle(mTitleNames[position]);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

            }
        });
    }

    public void setActionBarTitle(String title) {
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
    }
}
```

Does anyone have any ideas and/or code that they could share with me, showing how I'd solve this problem I have? Thanks so much!

## **Update:**

I probably should explain in a bit more detail. Due to my inexperience with all the terminology, I hope my explanation isn't too hard to follow.

So the whole purpose of `handleNewLocation()` is to be called by `onLocationChanged` so that when the user's location changes, it runs the code within `handleNewLocation()`, which gets the user's location and runs it against the set coordinates defined within the ArrayList above in the fragment. This will result in the the distance between the two locations to be updated to, for instance, 6.5 miles away, and so on, which is then displayed in a TextView in the ListView.

LocationsAdapter is a separate java class that I can call anywhere. - so I don't think that's part of the issue.

I have the data type `Word`, which is used by the ArrayList and contains code that calculates given user and location coordinates and converts them all into a DecimalFormat to be displayed in TextViews within the given ListView.

I think my issue is that... I need to have a reference to the ArrayList within the Locations class. I need to have a reference to the exact instance of the ArrayList and the ListView I set the LocationsAdapter to, as in: `mListView.setAdapter(new LocationsAdapter(getActivity(), locations, mLocation));`

My relative inexperience with Java comes in the form of me not knowing how to replicate all the current state of my code, but to instead have the all the Location-getting code in MainActivity and yet still have reference back to `mListView` for each fragment.

Does that make any sense? I'm having a somewhat hard time trying to explain it. I can provide the other classes for reference, if that helps at all?

Comment: All Fragments have a `getActivity()` method. If you make your Activity have a getter for the adapter (or the list data), your Fragments all can get from the shared Activity, and populate a ListView

Comment: Hello cricket_007, thanks for you response! I apologize, but is there any way you can show me this in a code example? I'm quite a visual learner and sometimes simple things can be lost by me if I don't "see" what I'm being taught, if that makes sense! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're trying to get a ListView of locations  here's an example with the location adapter in the Activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity 
    implements LocationListener {

    private LocationsAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // adapter = new LocationsAdapter();
    } 

    public LocationsAdapter getLocationsAdapter() { return adapter; } 

     // onLocationChanged... Add to adapter
```

Now, in the Fragments, you get that adapter like this

```
LocationsAdapter adapter = ((MainActivity) getActivity()).getLocationsAdapter();
listview.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I updated my main post with some additional info, and tried to explain it to the best of my ability- I hope it isn't too confusing! Let me know if there's anything else I need to provide to help clear things up.

Comment: Okay, a ListView doesn't care what class it's in. And you can rebuild an adapter with just an Arraylist. Therefore, your Fragments can create their own adapter and listview, but you need to get the Arraylist  from the Activity using a very similar approach to my answer.

Comment: And the location listener can easily be moved to the Activity. I personally would suggest that you start there, rather than worry about the listview yet

Comment: Ok gotcha. So I moved all the Location-related code into MainActivity, and my only issue now is simply the `mListView.getAdapter()` snippet. As expected, when I try to run it, it throws me a NullPointerException since mListView refers to the ListView within my word_list.xml, which is what my 2 fragments use as their ContentView, whereas MainActivity uses activity_main.xml. Since both Fragments use word_list.xml, and make use of the same ListView in separate instances, I wonder how I could have two instances of `mListView.getAdapter()`, and avoid any conflicting code?

Comment: I could be totally wrong (I have a hunch I may be), but here's what resolving this issue looks like in my rookie mind. To resolve `handleNewLocation()` so that it functions exactly as before, I would leave that method in its respective Fragment. I would then pass the Location that is retrieved within MainActivity over to the Fragment so that `handleNewLocation()` can still function. After that I would pass the entirety of `handeNewLocation()` back the MainActivity so that when `onLocationChanged()` is called, it can still call `handleNewLocation()` as before so all my code still works. Wrong?

Comment: Also, to add, I have no idea how I would actually go about doing this, in the case that it is a valid way to solve the problem.

Comment: You never needed `mListView.getAdapter()`. You store the adapter, as shown in my answer. Get it from the Activity, not the Listview

Comment: Okay, great! So how exactly do I implement this in my code and make everything function properly? Adding in `adapter = new LocationsAdapter();` into my Activity's onCreate() would require that I move the ArrayList over to the Activity as well, no? It seems to require that I put the proper params in, which are `(this, locations, mLocation)`  If that is the case, then how do I keep the code in my Fragment in onResume(): `locations = new ArrayList<>();` and in onPause(): `locations.clear();` working when there's no longer an ArrayList in the Fragment to refer to?

Comment: Your Fragment doesn't need the Arraylist. The adapter in the Activity does. In the Fragments onResume, you get that adapter and set it to the Listview of the Fragment

Comment: Ahh, my goodness, I finally get it! That all makes perfect sense. Everything is up and working perfectly. Thanks so much for your assistance!